# What are some ways to speed up a WordPress site that most people don't know?

Tags: optimization

I am looking for ways to speed up my site, https://whatifhq.com
I know this isn't the best place to post this, but I could not find anything else on the web other than "get a better server", "reduce your code", "the very obvious...".

What are some ways thats you reduced your WordPress website's load time?